# Configure Eclipse to launch a fixed project in a workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a small workspace with 3 projects. One main (Swing) application, two other projects that are just libraries.

Now, whenever I change stuff in my library project and want to execute i.e. run with Ctrl+F11) or debug , I have to select my main project first and run that.

Is there any way to set this up more smoothly, so I can just run my program regardless of which of my 3 project that is selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the "Launching" preference page. At the botton you can select *`Always launch the previously launched application`. That should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven you can create hierarchical structure of projects, i.e. head and child projects. In this case try to define Run/Debug profile on the parent's project level. Probably it will work from any other child project.

I personally have never try this and unfortunately cannot try this right now but I hope it will work for you.

If it does not work it seem you have to create your own eclipse plugin.

Good luck.